# How to pass data using delegates and protocols

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I have this first viewController which has UILabel in it and secondViewController which has UItextField and Add button. They are embedded in tabbar. I want to pass data from text field when add button is clicked to uilabel of first view controller.

```
protocol SendDelagate 
{
func setData(string:String) 
}
```

First View Controller is

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,SendDelagate{

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let vc = SecondViewController()
    vc.delegates = self
}
func setData(string: String) {
    label.text = string
  }  
}
```

And second ViewController is

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var delegates:SendDelagate?

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let text = textField.text!
    delegates?.setData(string: text)
     }
}
```

Comment: ` let vc = SecondViewController()` That's creating a NEW instance of `SecondViewController`, probably not the one you are seeing.

Comment: You can find lots of examples of different ways to do this. Which method to use depends on what you think your app will need as development goes along. Go to google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `uitabbarcontroller pass data between tabs swift`

Comment: How are you navigating the second vc from the first one? How are you navigating the second vc? Is it created using a storyboard?. Also in the `vc` you are creating in the first Viewcontroller will go out of scope once the `viewDidLoad` is completes

Answer (score 0):

SecondViewController is embedded in UITabbarController?

You can find SecondViewController instance via TabbarController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SendDelagate {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let secondViewController = tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first(where: { $0 is SecondViewController }) as? SecondViewController {
            secondViewController.delegates = self
        }
    }
    
    func setData(string: String) {
        label.text = string
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use User Defaults. So you save with your Add Button into User Defaults, and on `viewDidLoad` on the other view, you can load it.